# How to get type of reference (eg. if it is @book, @article, ...) from citefield in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, debugging, cite-package

**I want to see** title, year, abstract and **type of** a reference (eg. if it is book, article, ...) in citation in my draft (to be able to check if it is correct (for debugging;) ), I have many references).

### What I have

Bibtex entry:

```
@article{Wang2016,
    author = {Wang, Jane Ling and Chiou, Jeng Min and M{\"{u}}ller, Hans Georg},
    issn = {2326831X},
    journal = {Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application},
    month = {jun},
    number = {1},
    pages = {257--295},
    publisher = {Annual Reviews Inc.},
    title = {{Functional Data Analysis}},
    url = {http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-statistics-041715-033624},
    volume = {3},
    year = {2016}
}
```

My code:

```
    \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{
    \oldcite{#1} {
        \color{gray} \citefield{#1}{title}, \textit{\citefield{#1}{journaltitle}},
        \citefield{#1}{year} \textbackslash cite\{$#1$\} }
    }{} %
.
.
.
\cite{Wang2016}
```

Result:

> [10] Functional Data Analysis, *Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application,
> 2016* \cite{*Wang*2016}

What I want:

> [10] **@article** Functional Data Analysis, *Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application,
> 2016* \cite{*Wang*2016}

### My question

How can I put into cite **the type of reference** (@article, @book and so on)?

`\citefield{#1}{type}` does not work for me (according to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex it is something different).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\citefield{#1}{entrytype}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ivan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/231952/ivan) [points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597773/how-to-get-type-of-reference-eg-if-it-is-book-article-from-citefield#comment1498712_597773), the field is available as `entrytype`, so `\citefield{#1}{entrytype}` would work.

Usually it is more elegant and safer (for citation tracking purposes) to define a new `\...cite` command with `\DeclareCiteCommand` instead of putting together several `\...cite...` commands into one `\newcommand`.

Here you could go about as shown below. Use `\autocite` instead of `\cite` as your go-to command (a quick search-and-replace `\cite{` -> `\autocite{` and `\cite[` -> `\autocite[` with your editor should make this easy), so you can easily switch between the debug cite command and normal citations.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{entrytype}{\texttt{@#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{\texttt{\textbackslash autocite\{#1\}}}

\newbibmacro{checkcite}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
  }%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{entrytype}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\usebibmacro{journal}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{entrykey}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\checkcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{checkcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\checkcite}{\checkcites}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{check}{\checkcite}{\checkcites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=check}
% use autocite=plain or autocite=inline
% to go back to normal citations

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] @article ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998 \autocite{sigfridsson}]

Comment: Thank You a lot! :-)